# Regular Expression security pattern in symfony2

Tags: regex, symfony

I'm working on WSSE Authentication for a REST API (in symfony2)

In the security.yml i have to put a regular expression in the pattern parameter for restricting url access.

```
pattern:   ^/api/.*[^(connect|docs/.*)]
```

This regex is not working, and i have tried a lot of other combinaisons..

I would to restrict access for all API calls like :

```
/api/anything **BUT EXCEPT** for /api/connect **OR**  /api/docs/ **OR** /api/docs/anything
```

Comment: not sure it works but the rules are applied in the given order, so you may try to first deny the access on the both routes and apply a more global pattern after.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```
^/api/(?!(connect|docs/)).*$
```

Comment: Note that this will match /api/connectAnythingHere as well. You could possibly change `connect` to `connect$` to make sure it's not matched.

Comment: Ok, but in this case there is a 404 so there is not a problem.